# IE 9 Recursive Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, recursion, internet-explorer-9

Internet Explorer 9 goes into an endless loop while making a recursive ajax call to server. The following code works perfectly in Chrome :

```
function readMessages() {
//          console.log("Starting ajax");
            $.ajax({
                url : "read-messages",
                data: {userId:$('#usedId').val()}
            }).done(function(result) {
//              console.log("Ajax complete");
                $('#messages').append(result);
//              console.log("Recursive call - read-messages");
                readMessages();
            });
        };
```

After the first ajax is completed, IE executes the *readMessage()* function over and over, without actually waiting for an answer from the server. It seems I should somehow "reset" the request within jQuery (version 1.11.3 used)..

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you using `console.log` when running this script in IE9?

Comment: No, I commented them all, since IE seems to not like them

Comment: It's probably caching. `cache: false` might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting cache to false:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "read-messages",
    data: {userId:$('#usedId').val()},
    cache: false
}).done(function(result) {
    $('#messages').append(result);
    readMessages();
});
```

Comment: I just tried what you have suggested but unfortunately it did not solve the problem. I tested with Edge this time.

Comment: for some reason cache: false does not work. However $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); does the job.

Comment: @sashok_bg: that's odd, it should work. You haven't declared an AJAX type, so GET is used by default. Setting cache to false on GET request should work fine, as a timestamp is appended to the URL parameters, it's POST requests that are not cached (unless iOS/Safari). I'd look into why that setting doesn't work inline, as `ajaxSetup` is not recommended practice https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/

Comment: I used "post" to fix my problem. Finally I think it is the appropriate http "verb" :). Can you please update your answer with what you mentioned ?